# How to implement video Player based on location in flash?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I am trying to develop a browser based video player that plays a video only if the user belongs to certain country, Like youtube does.

I should be able to play a video if i am in India but not in Singapore? how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get user IP address in your player or return by server. For instance, in action script, you can get use IP by:

```
function GetUserIP() {
    var js="function get_userIP(){return java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();}";
    var userIPInfo:String=ExternalInterface.call(js).toString();
    return userIPInfo;
}
```

By comparing to some open IP to geo location conversion services (most of them are open and free), you should be able to detect which country the visit is from. Using this information you can apply your own logic of how the player will be behaved.